# How can I create bitmaps (in C)?

Tags: c, image-processing, bitmap

I am wondering how I can both import and export bitmaps to and from C. I'm basically lost on where to begin.

Comment: Create bitmap from scratch or create a bitmap via library?

Comment: You should learn the structure of BITMAP file..and then it not difficult to create a bitmap
it's just like playing with bits after you fill the file header..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bitmap in memory looks similar to this:

```
struct Image {
    int width;
    int height;
    char *data;    // 1 byte per channel & only 1 channel == grayscale
}

struct Image theImage;
theImage.width = 100;
theImage.height = 100;
theImage.data = malloc(sizeof(char) * theImage.width * theImage.height);
```

As to importing and exporting, there are some really simple file formats out there, take a look at [BMP](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Bitmap). For more complex formats you best use an already available library.

Most frameworks already have load/save methods for the most common fileformats. You could take a look at [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_image) if you're looking for a lightweight library.

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at ImageMagick's C API wrapper, [**MagickWand**](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php)? **[Here's](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/MagickWand/index.html)** the documentation if you want to peruse.

Answer (score 1):

I like using [SDL](http://libsdl.org/) with the dummy driver.  You can draw onto an in-memory buffer just like you would onto a screen, then save it out to a PNG or whatever with [SDL_image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/) or similar.

Another popular library for this is [GD](http://www.boutell.com/gd/).

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to use an appropriate library.  What library is appropriate will depend on what platform you are using.  On a GUI platform the GUI API/Framework will include these facilities.

Answer (score 1):

I like the [netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/)/[pbmplus](http://acme.com/software/pbmplus/) tools, although I usually like the command line; the API is efficient but not much fun to use.

This semester I wrote a significant amount of software for beginning students to use to manipulate images; you might want to check out the homework assignments and supporting software for the Tufts course [Machine Structure and Assembly-Language Programming](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/40/).

Comment: username + password required for the last link?

Answer (score 0):

The term "bitmap" is somewhat generic, unless you specifically mean a [Windows BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).

I'd recommend using an image processing library on your platform (like [gd](http://www.libgd.org/Main_Page/)). A good graphics library has routines to do input and output with images in various formats.

Answer (score 0):

[FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) is excellent. I've used this for my own game development work, and it supports tons of formats. Here's the list of features and formats supported - http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/features.html

Comment: I had a look at the 100-page API manual, and I'm not sure this is the source for someone who's having trouble getting started...